# MySQL slows down after INSERT

Tags: mysql, database, performance, web-applications, optimization

I run into performance issues with my web application. Found out that bottleneck is db. App is running on LAMP server(VPS) with 4 CPU and 2GB RAM.
After insertion of new record into DB (table with around 100.000 records) select queries significantly slows down for a while (sometimes several for minutes). I thought that problem is reindexing, but there is practicly no activity at VPS after insert. There are plenty of memory left, no need for swapping. CPU is idle.

Truth is, selects are quite complex:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.id), B.title FROM B JOIN A .... WHERE ..lot of stuff..
```

Both A and B has about 100K records. A has many columns, B only few but it is tree structure represented by nested set. B doesnt change very often, but A does. WHERE conditions are mostly covered by indexes. There are usually about 10-30 rows in result set.

Are there any optimizations I could perform?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include your "lot of stuff"... you could be doing 'like' comparisons or joining on unindexed varchar columns :)

you'll also need to look at indexing columns that are used heavily.

Comment: "lot of stuff" is generated on by app itself but there are no LIKE statements, just complex AND,OR,BETWEEN,= on indexed columns. And no unneeded joins.

Comment: You're gonna have to supply more info. 100 000 records really isn't that much, with a well defined schema even 10Million records shouldn't take "several minutes" as you mentioned.

Comment: selects dont take several minutes, but the slowdown does. selects are just considerably slower than normal. 10 secs and more.. what other info shoud I provide?

Comment: Ahhh, apologies... so after a couple of inserts it slows down for a while and then speeds up again? After an insert, try and establish whether it is time bound (maybe something happening in the background) or query count bound. What I'm thinking is perhaps after you inserted a whole bunch of stuff the query cache is cleared, and after you ran the query a couple of times it's built up again and goes back to "normal"

Comment: i dont think problem is bound by query count. latency goes back to normal, by running different variations of the select - where part is always different. I solved this by using result cache on application level - so the query is always slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is: DO NOT trust any CPU/RAM etc. measurements inside a VPS - they can be wrong since they don't take into account what is going on on the machine (in other VPS)!

As for the performance:

Check the query plans for all your SQL statements... use a profiler on the app itself and see where the bottlenecks are...

Another point is to check the configuration of your MySQL DB... is there any replication going on (might cause a slowdon too) ? Does the DB have enough RAM ? Is the DB on a different machine/VPS or in the same VPS ?

Comment: problem is, only tools i could use are inside VM.. i also checked vmstats, and machine really seems to be idling.

app is running responsibly, only problem is after insertion and it is db related. I tested it in isolated environment with no concurent requests.

there are no ongoing replication, i set innodb pool size to 512MB. apache and mysql are on the same machine.