# Disk-Read slows-down INSERT in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, indexing, mariadb, sql-insert

I am trying to optimize the speed of large INSERT queries on a MariaDB (10.0.31) on my InnoDB Table.

Here is the structure of the Table (131 Million rows):

```
Field__     Type___     Null    Key     Default     Extra   
ID_num_     bigint(45)  NO      PRI     NULL    
Content     varchar(250)YES             NULL    
User_ID     bigint(24)  NO      MUL     NULL    
Location    varchar(70) YES             NULL    
Date_creat  datetime    NO      MUL     NULL    
Retweet_ct  int(7)      NO              NULL    
isRetweet   tinyint(1)  NO              NULL    
hasReetwet  tinyint(1)  NO              NULL    
Original    bigint(45)  YES             NULL    
Url____     varchar(150)YES             NULL    
Favorite_c  int(7)      NO              NULL    
Selected    int(11)     NO              0   
Sentiment   int(11)     NO              0
```

Here is the output of `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Twit` (
 `ID_num` bigint(45) NOT NULL,
 `Content` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `User_ID` bigint(24) NOT NULL,
 `Location` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Date_create` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Retweet_count` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `isRetweet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `hasReetweet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `Original` bigint(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Url` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Favorite_count` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `Selected` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Sentiment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID_num`),
 KEY `User_ID` (`User_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is the structure of Indexes:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation   Cardinality     Sub_part Packed     Null    Index_type  Comment     Index_comment   
Twit    0           PRIMARY     1               ID_num          A           124139401       NULL     NULL       BTREE       
Twit    1           User_ID     1               User_ID         A           535083          NULL     NULL       BTREE
```

Here is the `show engine innodb status`:

```
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 8942256128; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 184
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
   Adaptive hash index 141954688 (141606424 + 348264)
   Page hash           4426024 (buffer pool 0 only)
   Dictionary cache    35656039 (35403184 + 252855)
   File system         845872 (812272 + 33600)
   Lock system         21251648 (21250568 + 1080)
   Recovery system     0 (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 252855
Buffer pool size        524286
Buffer pool size, bytes 8589901824
Free buffers            448720
Database pages          75545
Old database pages      27926
Modified db pages       0
Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 0, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 74639, created 906, written 39133
0.12 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 75545, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

I use the following Python code to download data from 3rd party source, then fill my table with it:

```
add_twit = (" INSERT INTO Table (ID_num, Content,....) VALUES (%s, %s, ....)")
testtime=0
t0 = time.time()
data_twit = []

#### Data Retrieving  ####
for page in limit_handled(...):
    for status in page:
        data_twit.append(processed_tweet)
####


##### MySQL Insert 
tt0 = time.time()
cursorSQL.executemany(add_twit, data_twit)
testtime += time.time() - tt0
####

cnx.commit()
print('Total_TIME ' + str(time.time()-t0))
print('Sqlexecute_TIME ' + str(testtime))
```

What does the code do:

It gets twits from 3rd party provider, 16 pages of them, with 200 twits (status) per page, so a total of 3200 rows to be added to the table for every iteratin (user). I tried inserting with one query per tweet (with `cursorSQL.execute(add_twit, data_twit)`, and with 16 queries of 200 tweets in a list too, but the fastest by few seconds is making one query of 3200 tweets using the optimized `cursorSQL.executemany` function.

For 3200 tweets, it takes about 10 seconds to download them and about 75 seconds to write them to the database, which seems a lot considering one tweet (row) currently takes 0.2ko in the table, hence 3200 is only 640 Ko. Shouldn't take 75 seconds...

What Happens when monitoring Disk-usage with `iotop`:

- During the Data-Retrieving part of the code (after the first iteration):

  - Read = 0.00 B/s
  - Write= 6.50 M/s

Disk actually keeps writing for several minutes at the 6Mbs/s rate after a large Insert

- During the SQL-Insert part of the code:

  - Read = 1.5 M/s
  - Write= 300 K/s

  Looks like the disk reading (for Index purposes I guess?) makes the writing rate fall down.

What I tried:

- Try to split Insert queries (instead of 1*3200 rows I tried 16*200 rows and 3200*1 row, didn't change anything, 1*3200 is slightly the fastest)
- Optimize Table (gained 15% speed)
- Remove unnecessary Index

My Questions:

- Why does the disk starts reading when I submit an INSERT query instead of writing? Is there a way to prevent that?
- Would remove all INDEX help speed-up INSERT?
- Do I need to remove the Primary-key (not the column, just the unique index on it), even though that sounds like a bad idea, and ( [MySQL slows down after INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962507/mysql-slows-down-after-insert) ) suggests not to?
- Any other suggestions?
- Also, why does the disk keep writing at the 6.00 Mb/s speed minutes after a large INSERT?

Comment: How about network latency? Is your database located on the same machine as your front-end process?

Comment: @joop , no its not, but it's on the same local network. Read queries are very efficient. I think the network is really efficent and with low latency.

Comment: Well, with < 2MB/s, the disk I/O is not saturated, so there must be a latency issue somewhere. (network, NAS?, too many synchronous writes/fsyncs?)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Please provide sample of the SQL for the inserts; not all of us know the mapping to SQL from Python.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the answer. I have updated the `CREATE TABLE` output. What do you mean by sample of the SQL?

Comment: @RickJames @joop I also updated the `show engine innodb status` as mysql permanently uses about 3go of RAM wether a query is running or not. I believed that would be an issue. It used to be about 8go before I cleaned the useless Index on other tables. Doing so, running time of the 3200 INSERT queries dropped from 75sec to 30sec. It is still a lot though and I believe there is some space for improvements.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 16go ram at the moment

Answer (score 2):

- About 60GB in the table?
- About 5GB in the User_ID index?  (See Index_length in `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Twit`.)
- Each `INSERT` has about 3200 new rows?  If this is wrong, then this is the main problem.
- You are calculating ID_num instead of using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?
- ID_num is monotonically increasing?  (Or at least approximately.)  If this is wrong, then it is the main problem.
- User_ID is quite random.

Analysis and conclusions:

- The data is being "appended to"; this does not have much impact on the cache (buffer_pool, which is 8GB).
- The `User_ID` index is being randomly updated; this keeps most of the index in cache or, possibly, spills.  If you have just now started spilling, then performance is on the decline, and it will get worse and worse as cache-misses increase.
- "I/O continues after write" -- This is normal.  For gory details, look up "InnoDB Change buffering".  Summary:  Updates of `INDEX(User_ID)` are delayed, but must occur eventually.

Partial solutions:

- More RAM.
- Increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of RAM; be sure not to lead to swapping.
- Surely you don't have more than 4 billion users?  Shrink `User_ID` to `INT UNSIGNED` (4 bytes) from `BIGINT` (8 bytes).  This will shrink the secondary index by about 25%.
- `DROP INDEX(User_ID)` -- Surely you need it?
- Do you use `ID_num` somewhere else?  If not, please explain its existence.
- Change from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` where appropriate.  (Won't help speed, but is a cleanup.)
- Use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of hand-rolled id.  (May not help.)

Benchmarking:

- I would not use any 'raw' I/O metrics -- they are confused by the 'blocking' of InnoDB and the Change buffer.
- Wait for "steady state".  That is, avoid small table, cold machine, burst, etc.  A graph of how long each 3200 took will have ups and downs because of such things.  But eventually it will reach a "steady state".  But, based on my analysis of the secondary index, that may decline to the point of 3200 rows taking 32 seconds (if using spinning disk).
- 3200 in 75 seconds does not make sense.  I think I really need to see the generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Amazing answer. I haven't investigated all off it, but just a quick question first: 100rows/sec (3200 rows in 32 sec) is the max limit according to you? After doing some cleaning and incresing the buffer_pool, I am close to 30/32 seconds now, should I stop trying to go faster? How did you come-up with this number?

Comment: Out-of-the-box, with a spinning drive (not SSD), InnoDB will handle 100 inserts/sec.  There are multiple tricks to get well past 100, perhaps 10K.  1M has been demonstrated, but it is tricky.  100 is the IOPs on a cheap drive; InnoDB does a minimum of one flush to disk to guarantee transactional integrity.

Comment: Inserting 100 rows in a single statement: 10x speedup.  Turning off a certain flag loses the guarantee but eliminates the 1 flush.  Etc.

Comment: `TEXT` and `BLOB` have issues due to off-record storage.  (You don't have such.)  Etc.

Comment: The relevant hints are: (1) batch the inserts if possible; (2) consider the tradeoff of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`.  See also my [_blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) on high speed ingestion; but that may be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you have indices, then you will have disk reads to seek through the indices. You will always have some reading taking place when you are inserting to find appropriate locations on disk.

Removing indexes would speed up your inserts at the expense of read operations later.

Whether you remove the primary index or not strongly depends on your use case, how much you trust the data source not to have full duplication. However, anything that requires to read the database using the primary key will pay heavily in performance later. However, this will speed up write operations.

You may want to consider other set ups for your RDBMS, such as sharding, which would allow you to distribute the load. There are only so many problems that can be solved without hardware scaling, or at least some kind of parallelism, and that may not be appropriate to your use case.

Comment: Thanks, very intereting answer. just some clarification on the primary-key part. Would removing it speed-up the writing process?

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, _do not remove the `PRIMARY KEY`_ !

Comment: @RickJames YIKES. That is a good point if doing accesses in a multithreaded environment.